# How can I fix these errors with Panda3D's sample projects?

Tags: opengl, python, linux, eclipse, panda3d

I just installed the latest Panda3D packages on a Mint 12 32-bit virtual machine. Then I downloaded and configured Eclipse and tried to run the Asteroids sample project. The window is created properly. But after rendering the scence once the game freezes. This happens with the other sample apps, too.

Here's the error log:

```
DirectStart: Starting the game.
Known pipe types:
  glxGraphicsPipe
(all display modules loaded.)
:display:gsg:glgsg(warning): Occlusion queries advertised as supported by OpenGL runtime, but could not get pointers to extension functions.
OpenGL Warning: glXChooseFBConfig returning NULL, due to attrib=0x6, next=0xffffffff
:display:glxdisplay(warning): No suitable FBConfig contexts available; using XVisual only.
depth_bits=16 color_bits=24 alpha_bits=8 stencil_bits=8 accum_bits=64 back_buffers=1 stereo=1 force_hardware=1 
AL lib: pulseaudio.c:331: PulseAudio returned minreq > tlength/2; expect break up
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 4765 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid enumerant
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 5703 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid operation
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 4654 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid operation
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 4654 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid operation
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 4765 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid enumerant
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 5703 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid operation
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 3057 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid operation
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 3057 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid operation
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 4765 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid enumerant
OpenGL Warning: No pincher, please call crStateSetCurrentPointers() in your SPU
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 4765 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid enumerant
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 5703 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid operation
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 4765 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid enumerant
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 4765 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid operation
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 4765 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid operation
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 5703 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid operation
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 3661 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid operation
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 3661 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid operation
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 4765 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid enumerant
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 4765 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid enumerant
:display:gsg:glgsg(error): at 5703 of panda/src/glstuff/glGraphicsStateGuardian_src.cxx : invalid operation
:display(error): Deactivating glxGraphicsStateGuardian.
```

What can I do to fix the problem ?

Comment: Have you installed your video card drivers yet?

Comment: I'm running it in virtualbox and the guest additions are installed

Comment: I've the same problem, have you fix it ?

Comment: no, I've moved to another distro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL driver emulation in virtual machines tends to be very unreliable, and more often than not plain useless.  You may need to turn down the framebuffer requirements in Panda3D to get it to work, for instance by putting `framebuffer-alpha #f` in your Config.prc file in order not to request an alpha framebuffer.  But given the general unreliability of these drivers, you should consider that it may be virtually impossible to get it to work at all.

However, you could choose to avoid OpenGL and use software rendering by putting `load-display tinydisplay` (or, depending on your Panda version, `load-display p3tinydisplay`) in your Config.prc file, but rendering will not be slower and you will not be able to use more advanced features.